# SQL Server 2012: error converting from nvarchar to numeric

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get my database within my application to search by phone numbers. I've got to the "Search Criteria Builder" screen, but I can't seem to get my query right.

This is the query I've tried and that is when I get the "converting from nvarchar to numeric" error:

```
SELECT        phoneNumber, serviceDate, firstName, lastName, billingAddress, emailAddress, vehicleMake, vehicleModel, vehicleYear, vehicleColor, vehicleMileage
FROM            [Table]
WHERE        (phoneNumber LIKE @phoneNumber + N'%')
```

Here is the table created:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
    [phoneNumber]    NUMERIC (18)  NOT NULL,
    [serviceDate]    DATE          NULL,
    [firstName]      NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [lastName]       NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [billingAddress] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [emailAddress]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [vehicleMake]    NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [vehicleModel]   NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [vehicleYear]    INT           NULL,
    [vehicleColor]   NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [vehicleMileage] INT           NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([phoneNumber] ASC)
);
```

If the VB code is needed, I will provide it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to treat phone "numbers" like strings, why are you storing them as numeric? You can do this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), phoneNumber) LIKE @phonenumber + '%';
```

(Also note that you don't need Unicode here - there is no number with umlauts.)

But better to change the data type of the column IMHO.

Comment: So you would change the phone number column to nvarchar or varchar?

Comment: Maybe, I don't really have enough info to decide on your data type, but if you decide to store as a string, use VARCHAR. What Unicode characters would you possibly need to support in a phone number?